# Problem calculating moment of inertia of a semicircle using simple integration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, moment-of-inertia

[image]

The problem asks to calculate the moment of inertia of a semicircle:

By simple integration using polar coordinates:

$$I_x=\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} y^2 {\rm d}A$$

Choosing a differential element with area ${\rm d}A$ , ${\rm d}A$= $\frac{r_0^2}{2}{\rm d}\theta$.

Where $r_0$ is the radius of the cricle.

$y=r_0\sin\theta$

$$I_x=\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} {r_0^2\sin^2\theta} \frac{r_0^2}{2}{\rm d}\theta$$

which evaluates to $\pi r_0^4/4$ while the solution should be $\pi r_0^4/8$. Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your area $dA$= $\frac{r_0^2}{2}d\theta$ is not the correct area as the value of $y$ varies across it.

[image]

You need to use the area which is shaded blue over which $y$ is a constant